# How can I know only the value of a specific index in Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

result = ["texi", "bus", "metro", "etc"] When there is this,

(1) I want to get from a specific index to the last index.
=> Expected values: bus, metro, etc

(2) I want to get only from a specific index to a specific index.
=> Expected values: bus, metro

Comment: In the case of `result = ["texi", "bus", "metro", "etc"]`, when the input value is non-destructive, your expected results are `console.log(result.slice(1))` and `console.log(result.slice(1, 3))`, respectively? Those results are `[ 'bus', 'metro', 'etc' ]` and `[ 'bus', 'metro' ]`, respectively. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The number of records in the array = `result.length`, so the last index (zero-based) would be `(result.length-1)`.